# Python: Separate things of string

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following string in my database: `items = '1;2 | 3;4'`

And I have to get information, like quantity and product, separating the information, I have to get the following, for example:

`1;2` = Product 1, quantity 2

`3;4` = Product 3, quantity 4

I tried anyway with split, partition with join, but it doesn't work.

I can get the first one with [0], but if there are others in the string I can't do the transformation.

Comment: What do you mean by "but it doesn't work"? Do you get an error? Do you get a wrong result? Please [edit] your question to the code of what you have tried so far, and it actual and expected behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = "1;2 | 3;4" # string
data = x.split("|") # data = ["1;2", "3;4"]
data = [i.split(";") for i in data] # data = [["1","2"], ["3","4"]]
data = [[int(i) for i in j] for j in data] # converts strings to ints
```

Now, `data[0][0]` gives the number of the first product and `data[0][1]` gives the quantity of the first product. Similarly for `data[1][0]` and `data[1][1]`

**Edit**

To clarify Andre's comment:

```
x = '1;2 | 2;4 | 3;8 | 45;1'
data = x.split("|") 
data = [i.split(";") for i in data]
data = [[int(i) for i in j] for j in data]

for i in data:
    print("Product number: " + str(i[0]))
    print("Quantity: " + str(i[1]))
```

Comment: But if you have more products? Example: x = '1;2 | 2;4 | 3;8 | 45;1', I needed him to return from everyone without having to pick a specific one, like [0][0], using join

Comment: Could you clarify your problem? My solution works for x = '1;2 | 2;4 | 3;8 | 45;1'. If you want to go through all the elements of the list, you can just use a for loop. I've edited my answer to show you this.

Answer (score 0):

```
txt = '1;2 | 3;4'

x = txt.split('|')

for i in x:
    print(i.split(';'))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.